# fl_chart custom Legend gets pushed down when section is empty

Tags: flutter, dart, fl-chart

I'm using the `PieChart` of [fl_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart) to display the distribution of locally saved documents. The percentages displayed in the chart are the result of the length of the two document type lists (See image below).
But when one List is empty I have a weird bug were my custom Legend gets pushed downwards. The `PieChart` and the Legend are positioned inside of a Row with flex factors on each children (2 for the `PieChart` and 4 for the Legend).
I really don't understand what pushes the Legend downwards because my `Expanded` widgets are always positioned inside of `Rows` so that the `PieChart` and Legend only take up the available, horizontal space and not the vertical space which happens in the bug (image 2).

PieChart widget:

```dart
class PersonalFilesCircularGraph extends StatefulWidget {
  const PersonalFilesCircularGraph();

  @override
  _PersonalFilesCircularGraphState createState() =>
      _PersonalFilesCircularGraphState();
}

class _PersonalFilesCircularGraphState
    extends State<PersonalFilesCircularGraph> {
  late List<FileTypeData> data;

  List<PieChartSectionData> getSections() => data
      .asMap()
      .map<int, PieChartSectionData>((index, data) {
        final value = PieChartSectionData(
          color: data.color,
          value: data.percent,
          showTitle: false,
          radius: 3,
        );

        return MapEntry(index, value);
      })
      .values
      .toList();

  @override
  void initState() {
/* Example getFileTypeData result
[
  FileTypeData(
    "Patient Questionnaire",
    patientQuestionnaires.length /
        (patientQuestionnaires.length +
            receivedPatientQuestionnaires.length) *
        100,
    const Color(0xFF3861FB),
  ),
  FileTypeData(
    "Received Patient Questionnaire",
    receivedPatientQuestionnaires.length /
        (receivedPatientQuestionnaires.length +
            patientQuestionnaires.length) *
        100,
    Colors.teal.shade400,
  ),
]; 
*/
    data = context.read<SessionBloc>().state.getFileTypeData;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<SessionBloc, SessionState>(
      listenWhen: (previous, current) {
        final bool listenWhen = previous.patientQuestionnaires.length !=
                current.patientQuestionnaires.length ||
            previous.receivedPatientQuestionnaires.length !=
                current.receivedPatientQuestionnaires.length;
        return !listenWhen;
      },
      listener: (context, state) {
        data = context.read<SessionBloc>().state.getFileTypeData;
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Container(
                constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                  maxWidth: 60,
                  maxHeight: 60,
                ),
                child: PieChart(
                  PieChartData(
                    sections: getSections(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: kMediumPadding,
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 4,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: data
                    .map(
                      (data) => Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                        child: buildLegend(
                          percent: data.percent,
                          text: data.fileName == "Patient Questionnaire"
                              ? L.of(context).patientQuestionnaires
                              : L.of(context).receivedPatientQuestionnaire,
                          color: data.color,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildLegend({
    required double percent,
    required String text,
    required Color color,
  }) =>
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 10,
                  height: 10,
                  color: color,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: kSmallPadding,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    text,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            "${percent.toStringAsFixed(0)}%",
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          )
        ],
      );
}
```

I display the chart widget inside a `CustomScrollView`, wrapped with a `SliverToBoxAdapter` inside of my home screen:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          elevation: 0.0,
          floating: true,
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
          title: Text(
            "Home",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        const SliverPadding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: kSmallPadding,
            horizontal: kMediumPadding,
          ),
          sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: PersonalFilesCircularGraph(),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

---

**EDIT:**

I just did some more investigation on this bug and placed a colored `Container` in my `CustomScrollView`, below the `SliverPadding` of the `CircularGraph` to check if the Column of labels expands downwards. But as you can see the colored Container is not effected. It just looks like the Legend is inside a `Stack` and positioned without effecting other widgets above and below.

```
const SliverPadding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    vertical: kSmallPadding,
    horizontal: kMediumPadding,
  ),
  sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
    child: PersonalFilesCircularGraph(),
  ),
),
SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    height: 60,
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: Where you able to solve this problem?

Comment: No, sorry stopped using Flutter lmao